# Apache Load Modules Time

Tags: apache, module

When are Apache modules loaded?
I remember that I read somewhere that some modules are loaded at the server startup, while others are loaded after a while so the startup wouldn't slow down.
Also if the administrator wanted to load a new module at the runtime, how is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) modules.  There is a lot of good info on these in the Apache Server documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/dso.html

Unfortunately, even when using DSO modules, you still have to restart the Apache server in order to load a new module.  There is currently no method for loading of Apache modules while the server is running.